# Testing a unit with implicit class in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, implicit-conversion

Imagine I have a service:

```
class ServiceA(serviceB: ServiceB) {

   import Extractor._

   def send(typeA: A) = serviceB.send(typeA.extract)

}

object Extractor {
   implicit class Extractor(type: A) {
      def extract = ???
   }
}
```

I want the `extract` method to be an implicitly defined because it doesn't directly relate to `A` type/domain and is a solution specific adhoc extension.

Now I would like to write a very simple unit test that confirms that `serviceB.send` is called.

For that, I mock `service` and pass a mocked `A` to `send`. Then I could just assert that `serviceB.send` was called with the mocked `A`.

As seen in the example, the `send` method also does some transformation on `typeA` parameter so I would need to mock `extract` method to return my specified value. However, `A` doesn't have `extract` method - it comes from the `implicit class`.

So the question is - how do I mock out the implicit class as in the example above as imports are not first class citizens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify a bunch of customised extract methods, you can do something like this:

```
sealed trait Extractor[T] {
  // or whatever signature you want
  def extract(obj: T): String
}
object Extractor {

  implicit case object IntExtractor extends Extractor[Int] {
    def extract(obj: Int): String = s"I am an int and my value is $obj"
  }
  implicit case object StringExtractor extends Extractor[String] {
    def extract(obj: String): String = s"I am "
  }

  def apply[A : Extractor](obj: A): String = {
    implicitly[Extractor[A]].extract(obj)
  }

}
```

So you have basically a sealed type family that's pre-materialised through case objects, which are arguably only useful in a `match`. But that would let you decouple everything.

If you don't want to mix this with `Extractor`, call them something else and follow the same approach, you can then mix it all in with a context bound.

Then you can use this with:

```
println(Extractor(5))
```

For testing, simply override the available implicits if you need to. A bit of work, but not impossible, you can simply control the scope and you can spy on whatever method calls you want.

e.g instead of `import Extractor._` have some other object with test only logic where you can use mocks or an alternative implementation.